# How do I check if a file is executable by other

Tags: shell, files, permissions

I'm looking for something like `test -x` but which only succeeds when a file is executable by "other", e.g. after `chmod o+x FILE`.

I could try to parse the output of `ls -l`,

```
-rw-r--r-x 1 me  me  0 Dec 23 10:47 t
```

but is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line to execute in shell (/bin/sh or /bin/bash):

```
PERMISSIONS=$(stat -c '%a' FILENAME); [ $((0${PERMISSIONS} & 0001)) -ne 0 ] && echo "executable by others" || echo "not executable by others"
```

Should be not a problem to create a script based on this.

Comment: By pushing this all into one line you make it very difficult for non-experts to understand your code.

Comment: I think the one line is pretty clear: `[ $(( 0$(stat -c '%a' $FILENAME) & 0001 )) -ne 0 ]`... Thanks!